# How to solve functional equation $f(x^{2}) = \frac{f(x)}{1 + x}$?

Tags: functions, continuity, functional-equations

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Find all $f : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $x = 0$ and satisfying $f(x^{2}) = \frac{f(x)}{1 + x}$.

I tried substituting $x$ with $-1, 0, 1$, but it doesn't really do anything.

I thought that maybe I should use limits here since I know that function is continuous at $x = 0$, so I also tried to decrease the power:

$f(x) = \frac{f(x^{\frac{1}{2}})}{1 + x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

$f(x^{\frac{1}{2}}) = \frac{f(x^{\frac{1}{4}})}{1 + x^{\frac{1}{4}}}$

$...$

I am not sure what to do next. Could somebody please give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noted that $$f(x) = \frac1{1-x} $$ is a solution. And in general you have $$\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$

Comment: Some other observations: $0$ is a solution, and the set of solutions is a vector space, which is non-zero by @dfnu's solution.

Comment: Do you want continuity only in $0$ or on the whole interval? In the latter case, I would guess that only multiples of $\frac 1 {1-x}$ are solutions. This is true at least if you look for analytic functions (power series). Can you see why?

Comment: @red_trumpet not really, could you please explain in a little more detail?

Comment: You can't substitute $x = \pm 1$ since $f$ is not defined there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $$f(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)\ldots (1+x^{2^n})f(x^{2^{n+1}})$$ As  $f(x^{2^{n+1}})$ tends to $f(0)$ we get $$f(x)=\lim_n\prod_{k=0}^n (1+x^{2^k})\, f(0) $$ Observe that (by induction) $$(1-x)\prod_{k=0}^n (1+x^{2^k})=1-x^{2^{n+1}}\to 1$$ Hence $$f(x)={f(0)\over 1-x}$$

**Remark** Once we know the solution we may argue as follows. The equation is equivalent to $$(1-x^2)f(x^2)=(1-x)f(x)$$ By iteration we get $$(1-x)f(x)=(1-x^{2^n})f(x^{2^n})\to f(0)$$